# When does the Torelli Theorem hold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hodge-theory

The Torelli theorem states that the map $\mathcal{M}_g(\mathbb{C})\to \mathcal{A}_g(\mathbb{C})$ taking a curve to its Jacobian is injective.  I've seen a couple of proofs, but all seem to rely on the ground field being $\mathbb{C}$ in some way.  So:

> Under what conditions does the Torelli Theorem hold?

Is algebraically closed necessary? Characteristic zero? It is known if there are any other base rings/schemes over which it is true?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.math.nyu.edu/~tschinke/papers/yuri/09torelli/torelli20.pdf

Comment: On the second page of that paper there is a claim that the Torelli theorem holds over any field. It doesn't seem to give a reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Torelli theorem holds for curves over an arbitrary ground field $k$ (in particular, $k$ need not be perfect).  A very nice treatment of the "strong" Torelli theorem may be found in the appendix by J.-P. Serre to Kristin Lauter's 2001 Journal of Algebraic Geometry paper *Geometric methods for improving the upper bounds on the number of rational points on algebraic curves over finite fields*.  It is available on the arxiv:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104247

Here are the statements (translated into English):

Let $k$ be a field, and let $X_{/k}$ be a nice (= smooth, projective and geometrically integral) curve over $k$ of genus $g > 1$.  Let $(\operatorname{Jac}(X),\theta_X)$ denote the Jacobian of $X$ together with its canonical principal polarization.  Let $X'_{/k}$ be another nice curve.

Theorem 1: Suppose $X$ is hyperelliptic.  Then for every isomorphism of polarized abelian varieties $(\operatorname{Jax}(X),\theta_X) \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} (\operatorname{Jac}(X'),\theta_{X'})$, there exists a *unique* isomorphism $f: X \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} X'$ such that $F = \operatorname{Jac} f$.

Theorem 2: Suppose $X$ is not hyperelliptic.  Then, for every isomorphism $F: (\operatorname{Jax}(X),\theta_X) \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} (\operatorname{Jac}(X'),\theta_{X'})$ there exists an isomorphism $f: X \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} X'$ and $e \in \{ \pm 1\}$ such that $F = e \cdot  \operatorname{Jac} f$.  Moreover, the pair $(f,e)$ is uniquely determined by $F$.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't been expecting this...talked to one of the local arithmetic people and they weren't sure, but figured it'd be false.  Thanks!