# Reference for Jacobians in characteristic $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, jacobians

I am looking for a basic reference for Jacobians of algebraic curves in characteristic $p>0$. I just want basic facts about the relation between the curve and its Jacobian.

I dont want to assume familiarity with the case of characteristic $0$.

Comment:  Weil, André Variétés abéliennes et courbes algébriques. (French) Actualités Sci. Ind., no. 1064 = Publ. Inst. Math. Univ. Strasbourg 8 (1946). Hermann & Cie., Paris, 1948. 165 

Comment: Milne has a nice article in the proceedings of a conference
on Arithmetic Geometry (1984) for those of us not fluent in Weil's
Foundations.

Comment: I think the editors are Cornell and Silverman.

Comment: this question is related.
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23848/when-does-the-torelli-theorem-hold

Comment: here is a link to notes by Milne, especially if you do not have access to the volume Donu referenced.

http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf

Comment: This might be overkill, but Chapter 4 of Hida's book "Geometric Modular Forms and Elliptic Curves" treats Jacobians of stable curves over arbitrary base schemes.

Comment: It also depends on what topics you want references for.  Milne's notes linked above prove the Jacobian exists and studies the abel maps from symmetric powers of the curve to the Jacobian, and shows that the (g-1)st such map gives the principal polarization, Theta.  He also proves Torelli's theorem, that the polarized Jacobian determines the curve.  If you want a proof of the Riemann singularity theorem for reading off dimensions of linear series from tangent cones to Theta, see G.Kempf, Annals of Math, vol.98 1973, or his lovely book, Abelian Integrals, 1983, from UNAM, Mexico, monografia #13.