# Where is a full proof of the precise Torelli theorem in the literature?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

The precise form of Torelli's theorem is as follows (translated from Serre's [appendix to Lauter - Geometric methods for improving the upper bounds on the number of rational points on algebraic curves over finite fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104247)):

> Let $k$ be a field, and let $X_{/k}$ be a nice (= smooth, projective and geometrically integral) curve over $k$ of genus $g > 1$.  Let $(\operatorname{Jac}(X),a)$ denote the Jacobian of $X$ together with the Jacobian's canonical principal polarization $a$, which is of degree 1.  Let $X'_{/k}$ be another nice curve. Any isomorphism $f: X \to X'$ defines by transport of structure an isomorphism $f_J: (J, a) \to (J, a')$.
>
> Torelli's theorem says that we get almost all of the isomorphisms: $(J, a) \to (J', a')$ in this way. More precisely:
>
> **Theorem 1**. Suppose $X$ is hyperelliptic.  Then, for every isomorphism of polarized abelian varieties $F: (\operatorname{Jac}(X),a) \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} (\operatorname{Jac}(X'),a')$, there exists a *unique* isomorphism $f: X \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} X'$ such that $F = \operatorname{Jac} f$.
>
> **Theorem 2**. Suppose $X$ is not hyperelliptic.  Then, for every isomorphism of polarized varieties $F: (\operatorname{Jac}(X),a) \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} (\operatorname{Jac}(X'),a')$, there exists an isomorphism $f: X \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} X'$ and $e \in \{ \pm 1\}$ such that $F = e \cdot  \operatorname{Jac} f$.  Moreover, the pair $(f,e)$ is uniquely determined by $F$.
>
> So, we conclude:
>
> $$\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Jac}(X), a) \simeq \begin{cases} \operatorname{Aut}(X) & \text{if $X$ is hyperelliptic} \\ \operatorname{Aut}(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 &  \text{if $X$ is not hyperelliptic} \end{cases} $$

Serre also states there that he does not know of a place where the precise Torelli theorem is proved in its full glory. In the algebraically closed field case, it is in Weil's *Zum Beweis des Torellischen Satzes*.

Is there a source that proves it over general fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23848/when-does-the-torelli-theorem-hold. See in particular Dan Petersen's answer and the comments below.

Comment: There are proofs by Torelli, Weil, Matsusaka, Andreotti, ...  The precise formulation you give follows from the theorem, p. 109, of Martens, H., *A new proof of Torelli's theorem*, Annals of Math. 78, no. 1 (1963), pp. 107--111, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970505?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents  In the hyperelliptic case, since the reflection of $W^1$ equals a translation of $W^1$, the general theorem reduces to your Theorem 1.